# how to obfuscate video URL

Tags: html, url, video, html5-video, obfuscation

Following code is used to display a video on a webpage using HTML5 Video Player.
I would need to obfuscate the url of the video, but since its pasted as `<source>` element i have no idea on how to change it without breaking the player.

I am not searching for something that takes days to figure out, but just something that doesnt make the URL so obvious.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>

  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="video.js"></script>

  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>


</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use non-ascii chars and spaces, then encode it.. (which of course invites encoding problems in the ends)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. how would encode the url in php in a way that the browser understands it but a person doesnt?

Comment: php? Sorry, I didn't see any php tag - I assumed javascript. BUT, I believe there is an urlEncoding component in PHP you could use. F.ex. an url like this: `/ æ/vid/ñ/ &id90` would be looking like this in string: `%2F%20%C3%A6%2Fvid%2F%C3%B1%2F%20%26id90`

Comment: That being said, there really isn't any point "obfuscating" an url like this as you can just paste in the obfuscated string in the browser address box and it will "decode" it..

Comment: hmmm.. is there anything i can do to make id more difficult? just not having it there in plain text... php and javascript, both are ok!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to first ask yourself why are you trying to do this. If you are trying to prevent the user from downloading your video, then don't use a HTML5 video player.

Comment: the page will be visible for only one time, and the viewer doesnt know that.. so all i need is a efficient way to hide the url or to fool the viewer to reload the page. i am thinking of a javascript code that rebuilds the url into a string. i pass a series of numbers in an array, and all he does is to take the according letters in the alphabet and rebuild it..